# Fluent Validation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, fluentvalidation

I tried to replace validation from my previous project on Asp.net MVC 4 to Asp.net Core. And have some problems. The flow in Asp.net Core project like that:

Middleware => ControllerCTOR => FluValidator => Filter => Action

Also when some of Rules in FluValidator failed it's just return response with errors through Middleware stack to client. But I need to have access to ModelState in Filter or in  Action.

Why this don`t work correct? Or, if it's actually right flow, how to make it go deeper to Action?

Startup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
                        {
                            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelAttribute));
                        })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
        env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CorpLight API V1");
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticateMiddleware>();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Middleware

```
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }
```

Validator

```
public class CardInformationRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<RequestModel<CardInformationRequest>>
{
    public CardInformationRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Request.RU)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.Request.Currency)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.Request.AccountNumber)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CardController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICardRepo _cardRepo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CardController(ICardRepo cardRepo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _cardRepo = cardRepo;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<MessageWithElements<CardInformation, CardInfo>> CardInformations(RequestModel<CardInformationRequest> request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new InvalidParametersException($"can't be empty");

         //logic

    }
}
```

Filter

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //logic
        }
    }
}
```

Typical Valid Json:

```
{ 
  "request": {
    "ru": "string",
    "accountNumber": "string",
    "currency": 1
  }
}
```

Typical Invalid Json:

```
{ 
  "request": {
    "ru": "string",
    "accountNumber": "string",
    "currency": 0
  }
}
```

When currency NOT zero it's valid, and reach filter. But when it's zero, NotEmpty become failded and flow go back.

Typical response with Valid request:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      <object fields>
    }
  ],
  "messageText": "string",
  "messageNumber": 1
}
```

Typical response with Invalid request (400 Bad Request):

```
{
  "Request.Currency": [
    "'Request. Currency' must not be empty."
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please specify what actually is not working correctly. Having access to the ModelState or something else? Describe the problem more clearly, it's too broad. Regards.

Comment: For example I start debug. If send valid request it will go through Middleware to ControllerCTOR, then Fluentvalidator starts check model by Rules. As model is valid property IsValid in ModelState become true. And request goes to Filter and then to Action where I can check is ModelState valid and make some format response.

BUT if model is invalid. It just return response with error by failed rules without reaching Filter or Action.

Comment: Please add code where you `app.UseYourMiddleware`

Comment: Done. Add Configure method of Startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was in Filter. Because of OnActionExecuting method request never reach. After validation if there are any failed Rule context goes straight to OnResultExecution and return response.

```
public class ValidateModelFilter : Attribute, IAsyncResultFilter
    {
        public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                throw new InvalidParametersException(context.ModelState.StringErrors());

            await next();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Execution flow actually reaches both `ValidateModelAttribute` and action even if the model isn't valid. But there is a specific case when `Request` property is `null` and `CardInformationRequestValidator` throws an exception during validation. For example when the validator tries to check this rule

```
RuleFor(x => x.Request.RU)
    .NotNull()
    .NotEmpty();
```

it tries to get `RU` property value but it throws `NullReferenceException` because `x.Request` is `null`. So the solution is to update validation logic

```
public CardInformationRequestValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Request)
        .NotNull()
        .DependentRules(() =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Request.RU)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.Request.Currency)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.Request.AccountNumber)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty();
        });
}
```

Read more [in docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#complex-properties) and [on github](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/851).

Comment: Nope. Request object filled. Example:
{ 
  "request": {
    "ru": "string",
    "accountNumber": "string",
    "currency": 0
  }
}

When currency NOT zero it's valid, and reach filter. But when it's zero NotEmpty become failded and flow go back. I don't know why, maybe some configurations prevent going further if validator failed.

Comment: @RomanMakarenko Hmm this is strange because it works fine for me. And, if you are sending json you are missing `[FromBody]` before action parameter otherwise it's not binded I believe.

Comment: @RomanMakarenko Also, please add what output you have when the input is invalid.

Comment: added response body to question article.

Comment: Also I add [FromBody] and there is no changes.

Comment: @RomanMakarenko Thanks for info. So you have `RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware` and `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` that could short-circuit request before reaching controller. I'd think the problem is there. Or on another hand, what response do you have if you replace `throw new InvalidParametersException($"can't be empty");` with `return null;` in controller?

Comment: Well, I have already tried to disable all Middleware and it doesn't help. Request simply go to validator and if failed - return response with errors. As to replacing `throw new InvalidParametersException` in controller. I made mistake when I copied code there is denial: `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`. But even so request can`t get to controller so it no matter what logic there.

Comment: @RomanMakarenko I suppose it gets action filter and code inside the filter sets `context.Result` value. If so it's no wonder that controller action isn't fired.

Comment: Nope, same way if request is valid it goes to filter. Request invalid - process stops, generate error and return response. Maybe problem associated with versions (Microsoft.AspNetCore.App v2.1.1; Microsoft.NETCore.App v2.1; FluentValidation.AspNetCore v8.1.3) but I have no idea how.

Comment: @RomanMakarenko Well, I have exactly the same versions of frameworks and packages and it works just fine for me. So I don't know what to say else.

Comment: I have found the solution. The problem was in Filter. Because of OnActionExecuting method request never reach. After validation if there are any failed Rule context goes straight to OnResultExecution and return response. Thanks for your help!!!